# Is Declaring Jquery $(window) Redundant

Tags: jquery

I don't understand why declaring a variable of the current open window is necessary.  Isn't that technically the only window your code can affect?  Why use $(window)?

Comment: Don't you want to do things with the window? We obviously need a variable for it to do stuff with it. `$(window)` is just the syntax to select the element?

Comment: $(window) creates a jQuery object from the window object, so you can do jQuery stuff with the window object. I think that is fairly straight-forward.